# add UIView loading screen on top window of application in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add an UIView with a UIActivityIndicatorView does not seem to work. Any help appreciated.

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:1];
UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center = overlayView.center;
[overlayView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview:overlayView];
```

Trying also adding it like this

```
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
 [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:overlayView];
```

seems to work but the navigationbar is not getting hidden

Comment: Creating your frame did you try to set it up like this: UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

Comment: Nope let me try

Comment: Nope same result. Seems like when the navigation bar is not hidden it shows up infront of the overlayview...

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Does not show the view with UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview:overlayView]; but shows the view with [self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
 [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:overlayView]; but still the navigation bar shows infront of it. The loading view does not cover the navigation bar...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add an overlay to a current shown controller like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    overlayView.alpha = 0.8;
    [self.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
}
```

This overlay should cover all the current window.

Comment: i will try and i will let you know

Comment: nope this does not seem to work

Comment: Ok, try to edit your question and add all the cod for testing, ok? Include the ViewController side.

Comment: it is not my code and is than 2000+ code lines in the viewcontroller so i can not add it

Answer (score 0):

In your viewcontroller class, use the following code to display your overlay view.

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.7]];
[self.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
```

The key here is to use viewcontroller's view's window object so that in case of `NavigationController` or `TabBarController`, complete view is overlaid along with navigation bar and or tab bar.

Comment: Nope this is not working...

Comment: Then you better share the complete code. Possibly the issue is something else.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your code since I checked your own code you pasted in the question and that is working just fine.